# Uploading waypoints, spline waypoints to APM Quadcopter

Tags: c#

I'm building my mini GCS. I had Arm/Disarm are working correctly, but I'm stuck in how to send the waypoints to my drone. I need to send a Spline waypoints. I've tried `MAV_CMD_NAV_SPLINE_WAYPOINT` and set the parameters as required, but it does not send anything to my drone .

Here is my code:

```
MAVLink.mavlink_command_long_t alaa = new MAVLink.mavlink_command_long_t();
alaa.target_system = 1;
alaa.target_component = 1;
alaa.command = (ushort)MAV_CMD.MAV_CMD_NAV_SPLINE_WAYPOINT;
alaa.param1 = 0; // hold time
alaa.param4 = 0; // yaw angle
alaa.param5 = latt; // desired latitude
alaa.param6 = longg; // desired longitude
alaa.param7 = altt; // desired altitude
byte[] packet = mavAlaaWrite.GenerateMAVLinkPacket10(MAVLink.MAVLINK_MSG_ID.COMMAND_LONG, alaa);
Serial.Write(packet, 0, packet.Length);
```

Can someone please make a simple example by sending mission spline waypoints to my drone by clicking on a command button?

I'm programming using C# Windows forms.

Many thanks in advance.